# How to get my Mobile number in Google assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am developing an app in Google Assistant platform. I need to fetch the mobile number of the mobile from which the Google Assistant action is invoked.

Is this possible in Node JS fulfillment Code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

The Actions on Google Platform runs on a variety of devices, including those that do not have a mobile number.

Comment: (You may wish to update your question to explain what you're actually trying to do and we can discuss how to do it, but as asked, this is the answer.)